# Power Automate Assigning Approvers from Different People

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate, appstore-approval

I have a question regarding how to specify the number of approvers from an approval. Here's the context.

My office wants to automate requests by using Approvals. But we only want to limit the approvers to be just the HR and the supervisor of the respective division, so just 2 people. Of course, the name of the supervisor may vary and at times it could refer to a normal staff member as well.

Under the normal Approvals process, the assigned approvers could be done automatically. But the reports of these Approvals requests will be recorded in a specific List for easier accessibility and screening. Hence this roundabout method I used here so far.

Does anyone have an idea to insert dynamic content that limits the number of approvers in the 'Assigned to' row? So the approvers listed in the action are always the same people a staff wrote in the Approval form in the first place. I no longer need to input manually who will approve the requests.

[image: The code I tried to run so far]

Basically I want the names in this approval form
[image: Basically I want the names in this approval form]

To be included as a dynamic content in this 'Assigned to' part
[image: To be included as a dynamic content in this Assigned to part]

Did I miss some steps?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Is it anyhow related to MS Teams development?

Comment: It's for Approvals and a feature in MS Teams, so I believe it's still related.

My problem here is just the approvers that were written in the Approval file can't seem to be included as a dynamic content. That's why the email of the approvers need to be written manually. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried because in my experience, getting the approvers to be dynamic is no different to other dynamic fields in an action.  I literally just did it on my own tenant.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, getting the approvers to be dynamic is no different to other dynamic fields in an action. You can use variables to achieve so and can pass those in flow action.

Flow Steps:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks. I think this could work. I'm sorry but I still don't understand how to define the approver's emails though. Does this mean I need to compose and parse the JSON from the submission to get the value I need to initialize?

Comment: Yes, you can do that